# How to kill session of login users when admin changes right asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, user-roles

I am working on a project which have `3 Roles`

- Admin
- Super User
- User

Admin is able to control every users. When I am changing any user rights, I want to see if user already loged in or not, if so then kill that user session and redirect him/her to login page.

But I am not getting idea of how to do so. What I want to implement is a sort of synchronization that as soon as admin makes any changes to users then application would work in that fashion.

I have implemented changes like

```
var userForUpdation = (from o in entitiesForUpdation.Users
                                   where o.UserID == user.UserID
                                   select o).FirstOrDefault();
userForUpdation.User_Status = false;
entitiesForUpdation.SaveChanges();
```

As see User_Status has been made false. Now that particular user can not access to his/her account. But for me this is happening, `The loged in user can access to application until he/she log out and login again`. I want to immediately kill the session of that particular user so he/she can not use the application any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `immediately` kill the session from outside that session. But you can set a flag inside the `Application` which will be checked on each request and will abandon current session if set.

To set the flag for a user:

```
if (Application["SessionAbandonFlags"] == null) 
    Application["SessionAbandonFlags"] = new List<string> ();

((List<string>) Application["SessionAbandonFlags"]).Add(currentUser);
```

And in `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application["SessionAbandonFlags"] != null && 
           ((List<string>) Application["SessionAbandonFlags"]).Contains(currentUser))
    {
        // Do what is needed here
        Session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

This code can of course be improved. I just wanted to give you the direction.

Comment: Don't forget to call [`Application.Lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can [store custom information in the Forms Authentication Ticket](http://www.danharman.net/2011/07/07/storing-custom-data-in-forms-authentication-tickets/) by storing JSON within the `UserData` property.

So if you stored a field within your `User` table within the database you could have an `UpdatedTimeDate` field that is updated with the current UTC time whenever user roles are changed. Store this value within the Forms Authentication Ticket.

During the [`HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest(v=vs.110).aspx) event you can check this value matches the value stored in the database, and expire the login session if it does not. Therfore any changes to user roles will cause the user to be logged out.

This has the advantage of storing this information within the authentication mechanism itself, and it will also work across servers in a cluster whereas storing data within the `Application` object does not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remotely kill a session after changing something as admin. One solution that comes to my mind is creating an action filter that checks on every request if users role, access level or status has changed and kills the session if it's true.